# Code change of a Python script for posts on discord

Tags: python, discord.py, webhooks

I have a script to build with a friend (I'm learning) that he does a daily search in an api, treats the data and sends it to discord via webhook.  the issue is that the api changes once a day, and it is necessary to change part of the api manually every day.  I would like to automate this.  I'll do the example below:

```py
# from mir4_webhook import objects
import json
import requests
from mir4_webhook.objects import Guild


class MirAPI:
    base_url: str = "https://api.mir4.gq/v1/clan/52289808/roster/"

    def __init__(self, roster: str = "32"):
        self.url = self.base_url + roster

    def request(self):
        url = self.url
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()

        return Guild.from_dict(data)
```

The line:

```py
def __init__(self, roster: str = "32"):
```

the number **32** refers to a date (example 3 days ago) so whenever the script is executed and it has the number 32, it will result in the same value.

So you could just add two methods, then, within the API class

```py
def fetch_history(self, roster: str):
    ...
    ...
```

then `api.fetch_history('32')`
could give you the historical data.

For that you'd need to do some local sto and you convert those classes to a dictionary that can be stored in a json file. And add a new method for the dataclasses called somehting like `def to_dict(self):`
and you convert those classes to a dictionary that can be stored in a json file.
Then you would store the previous day and use it to add comparisons.

https://api.mir4.gq/v1/latest
this will give you what the latest dataset is `"id": "35", "day": "20221020"`, but I'm not able to add these variables alone.  can anybody help me?  it could be using the other api, which every day updates and changes the variable we need “35” today, “36” tomorrow... so on.  is a way to save the history in json so that it can be consulted later for comparison level.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the id increases by 1 every day, meaning that at any given moment the id is equal to the amount of days that have passed since this began.

You can use the `datetime` module to check the difference between two dates. By hardcoding the first date, you can just call `today()` to get the current date, and subtract them to get the amount of days that have passed.

*Disclaimer: I don't know day 0 and I won't look it up, this is just an example. You should be able to figure out what day 0 is.*

```py
>>> from datetime import date
>>> first_day = date(year=2022, month=10, day=22)  # This is not the actual first day
>>> today = date.today()
>>> today - first_day
datetime.timedelta(days=1)  # The amount of days since first_day is 1
>>> todays_id = str((today - first_day).days)
```

The logic behind this is that if yesterday was `day 0`, then today is day `amount_of_days_since_day_0` which is `1`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I thought in a similar way.  but the problem that the ID that the api returns is not referring to the day, it is a sequential ID as in the example of the return of the other api that refers to the ID of the current day: ```"id": "35", "day": "20221020"``` in this return, it is the 20th of the 10th month of the year 2022, the ID of this day is 35. when it is the 21st = 36 and follows the sequence regardless of the month or day, each day adds +1 to the ID.

Comment: @RodrigoRios I don't see the problem. Each day adds +1 to the ID, so if you reverse that and do `-1` then at some point it was 0 or 1 and you know the start date. Am I missing something else? If `20/10/2022` is `35`, then 35 days before that was ID 0.